# Angular. Animating flex elements

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular2-animation

Hello. I have a small component that looks like so:

[image]

when search is clicked it turns into:

[image]

In the markup there are two `flex` elements: for header (`flex: 1`) and for search. On search click I hide first one and expand second one. Now I want to animate the transition.

I started with animating header element. First I tried animating `width`:

```ts
transition(':enter', [
    style({width: 0, 'max-width': 0}),
    animate(500, style({width: '*', 'max-width': '*'})),
]),
transition(':leave', [
    style({width: '*', 'max-width': '*'}),
    animate(500, style({width: 0, 'max-width': 0})),
]),
```

[image]

It's almost instant on enter and the `Header` word sliding to the left instead of shrinking. (setting `overflow: hidden` on header breaks animation completely)

Then I tried animating `flex-grow`:

```ts
transition(':enter', [
    style({'flex-grow': '0.001'}),
    animate(500, style({'flex-grow': '1'})),
]),
transition(':leave', [
    style({'flex-grow': '1'}),
    animate(500, style({'flex-grow': '0.001'})),
]),
```

[image]

Better animation on enter and almost no animation on leave. Combining the two together:

```ts
transition(':enter', [
    style({'flex-grow': '0.001'}),
    animate(500, style({'flex-grow': '1'})),
]),
transition(':leave', [
    style({width: '*', 'max-width': '*'}),
    animate(500, style({width: 0, 'max-width': 0})),
]),
```

[image]

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZVMP2xbG00kqQUVz7hiQ?p=preview)

Any ideas how can I fix the sliding header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to animate input element as well. In this case only `width` property needs to be animated:

```
  trigger('anim', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({width: 0}),
      animate(250, style({width: '*'})),
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({width: '*'}),
      animate(250, style({width: 0})),
    ]),
  ]),
```

[image]

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PxDY307mWT9eDSV71eWr?p=preview)